# ADB command for SIM 2 network scan

Tags: python, adb

Does anyone know how to adapt the adb command below to perform a network scan on SIM card 2 for a dual SIM handset?  Using Python the below command performs a network scan but defaults to SIM 1, is there another command I can add to toggle to SIM2?

```
subprocess.check_output('adb shell am start -n com.android.phone/com.android.phone.NetworkSetting')
```